# Redis user name setting for Kubernetes deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, redis, amazon-memory-db

i am using redis memory db cluster for cahching . i am tring to set a redis user name inside my kubernetes deployment, as my redis memory db version 6.2 , i have set user name inside deployment. is there a way to set this ? currently i geting error like
"redis connection tls true
Redis connection established
adapter listening on [::]:9123
adapter listening on [::]:9122
LTE / UDP forward with port : 35115
LTE / UDP forward with port : 44801
MQTT connection established
WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair or user is disabled.
panic: WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair or user is disabled.                                                                        "
can you help me how to solve it ?

i have tried to modif redis config map to set user name

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would have the same problem. Is there an environment variable like `REDIS_USER` or `REDIS_USERNAME` which allows to specify the user for the login like in the `redis-cli -u user:password@host:6379`?

Something like this?

```
          env:
        - name: REDIS_USERNAME
          value: "$(REDIS_USERNAME)"
        - name: REDIS_USER
          value: "$(REDIS_USER)"
```